# Load a page in parent window from Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe and within the onload of the iframe I want a line (or however many lines) of code that will reload the main page (the page in which the iframe sits) with a particular url.  What is that line of code?

Comment: Reloading the parent page will load the iframe again, reloading the parent page again... Do you really want to get stuck in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should would:

```
top.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```